# Adding values next to a dynamic column of data from import range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet containing raw data about students, teachers and classes. [Example rawdata.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uplBep5PncXQVZe23cHNt7ZzvTsZs7BOl4C3U-MPpFQ/edit#gid=0)

From time to time the values in this sheet might change as students change classes, join or leave the school.

I've made an app script that creates a ['workbook'](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VxnfxLkZQypU1lSenIYs5UhfJlPT-sQE2bkIhCk_AIU/edit#gid=1353480455) for each teacher. Each workbook contains a sheet for each class that teacher teaches and this also generates a query in cell A1 of each sheet.

This importrange query function then creates the list of students that belongs in each sheet.

A teacher then enters grades for each student.

This much works, but if the data is updated, for example a new student added to 'rawdata' then the teacher's class list will shift and the entered grades no longer match the correct student.

Is there any relatively simple solution to this?
(A previous version of this with appscript was running to 2000 lines before I gave up on that method as too complex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the grades to be "linked" to each student (logically), you need to write the name of the student somewhere.

What you could do is add a sheet for the teacher, and make them enter manually the name of the student next to the grade (they won't need to see the list for that since they'd have to have the name of the student to know their grade). If you want them to only be able to add a student name, you could even use validation for them to have a dropdown where they can select the student.

Then, if you want to be able to see the grades of the students directly on the 1st sheet, you can use Vlookup, this way even if the list changes, the grades will still be linked to the right students

Comment: Thanks for your help. So in other words there is no way to achieve what I'm attempting purely with formulas.